# How to extract data from a csv file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');

csv()
 .from.stream(fs.createReadStream('nodetest.csv'))
 .to.array(function(data, count) {
    var lastLine = data.slice(-1)[0];
    var needed = lastLine.slice(-1)[0];
    console.log(needed);
  });
```

I'm trying to extract some data from a csv file. Lets say my csv file contains these rows

`ABB|BCC|CDD|DEE
 eff|fgg||ghh|hii
 ijj|JKK|kll|LMM`

and I only need to extract`kll` from the last line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using this npm module : [csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv).

You can use a simplier code to parse your CSV. And for extracting the needed value you could do :

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');

var parser = csv.parse({delimiter: '|'}, function(err, data){
    var lastRow = data[data.length-1];
    var wantedValue = lastRow[lastRow.length-2];
    console.log(wantedValue);
});

fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/file.csv').pipe(parser);
```

Notice that this code is static, but it meet your requirement. Your CSV must stay the same. Notice that I set `|` as a delimiter. By default CSV use the coma delimiter (hence the name Comma Separated Values).

The documentation for the parser can be found [here](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/).